# unknown column client in 'field list'

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am getting the error unknown column client in 'field list' when trying to insert into the database

This my code shows primary key and foreign key

```
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ParamKey")
    private long paramKey;

    public long getParamKey() {
        return paramKey;
    }

    @Column(name = "FeedKey")
    public long getFeedKey() {
        return feedKey;
    }

    public void setFeedKey(long feedKey) {
        this.feedKey = feedKey;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "clientKey")
    public Client getClient() {
        return client;
    }

    public void setClient(Client client) {
        this.client = client;
    }
```

Hibernate query as follows

```
insert 
        into
            M_FeedInputParams
            (client, createdBy, createdTs, feedKey, jobInstanceKey, logicalDeleteTms, paramName, paramOper, paramValue, paramValueType, sourceInstanceKey, updatedBy, updatedTs) 
        values
            (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

The client should be `clientKey` how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to change your getter and setter to:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "clientKey")
private Client clientKey;

//Getter & Setter
public Client getClientKey() {
    return clientKey;
}

public void setClientKey(Client client) {
    this.clientKey = client;
}
```

Comment: so should i have two different declarations like this? private Client client;
 private long clientKey;  the second didnt worked

Comment: No but you don't have the declaration long clientKey... Your class Client is the one with the id. In this class you'll save an Instance of Client...

Comment: i should return clientKey right? it dosent make any difference

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `client` field exist in `M_FeedInputParams` table.

Comment: my table has ClientKey but its a foreignkey of type Client so iam passing client type

Comment: i thing its not properly mapping.with Client

Answer (score 0):

this type of problem occurs due to column name different rational column name should be same with datatype

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "addres_id")
private Address studentAddress;
public  StudentMany(){}
```

above two annotation are important .make it like that your problem may be solve .